# Translating cucumber to rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, cucumber

How to write the following feature in rspec?

> Feature: Signing in;
>         In order to use the site
>         as a user,
>         I want to be able to sign in
>
> ```
>   Scenario: Signing in via confirmation
>     Given there are the following users:
>       |email            |password|
>       |user@example.com |password|
>     And "user@example.com" opens the mail with subject
>       "Confirmation instructions"
>     And they click the first link in the email
>     Then I should see "Your account was successfully confirmed"
>     And I should see "Signed in as user@example.com"
> ```

Comment: For clarity- Are you asking how a person would translate this cucumber test directly to a stand alone RSpec, or how to actually run an RSpec from within a Cucumber test?

Comment: I wish to use RSpec only, no cucumber, so I guess I'm asking > How to translate directly to stand alone RSpec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the feature from the first edition of *Rails 3 in Action*, which I'm currently re-writing into a second edition. The second edition's feature goes like this:

```
feature 'Signing in' do
  before do
    Factory(:user, :email => "ticketee@example.com")
  end

  scenario 'Signing in via confirmation' do
    open_email "ticketee@example.com", :with_subject => /Confirmation/
    click_first_link_in_email
    page.should have_content("Your account was successfully confirmed")
    page.should have_content("Signed in as ticketee@example.com")
  end
end
```

This is using Capybara's new feature syntax, which for all intents and purposes is the same as RSpec's `context` blocks. By using a `before` you set up a user that you can use inside this feature. Inside the scenario, you use the `open_email` method (provided by the email_spec gem) to open the email, and the `click_first_link_in_email` method also provided by that gem to perform those two steps.

That then takes you to a page where you should be able to see the two messages as so desired.

Comment: this is good, but then I get this error > 'expected there to be content "Your account was successfully confirmed" in "\n\n\n\n  \n\n  Resend confirmation instructions\n\n\n      \n      1 error prohibited this user from being saved:\n      Confirmation token is invalid\n\n\n  Email\n\n  \n\n  Sign inSign upForgot your password?\n\n"'

Answer (score 1):

Give [turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip) gem a try.

> Turnip is a Gherkin extension for RSpec. It allows you to write tests
>   in Gherkin and run them through your RSpec environment. Basically you
>   can write cucumber features in RSpec.

Comment: thanks, but I'd prefer not to use the gem. Just trying to get my rspec skills up :)